# Flash Video Player Auto Start and Control Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, flash

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="500" height="208">
    <param name="movie" value="Myanimation.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="Myanimation.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500" height="208" autostart="false" ></embed>
</object>
```

I'm using this code to play a Flash video. The auto start is not working.  And how can I create Start/Stop/Pause buttons?

Comment: Care to either post your public site's URL where it is not working or the complete source code that you used here?

Comment: The buttons are to be created in flash, google flash tutorial to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this links : http://jquery.malsup.com/media/video.html

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

http://videolightbox.com/rq/jquery-video-player/